Is there anyway to make a uber (fat) jar to an app which use javafx from the command line?
Is there anyway to make a uber (fat) jar to an app which use javafx from the command line?
I tried this:
    # Step 1: Collect all JAR files for the classpath
$jarFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "H:\_myapp\lib" -Filter *.jar -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
$classPath = $jarFiles -join ";"

# Step 2: Define source and output paths
$sourcePath = "H:\_myapp\src\sample\editor"
$outputPath = "H:\_myapp\out"

# Step 3: Collect all Java files recursively
$javaFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter *.java -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }

# Step 4: Compile using javac
javac -cp $classPath $javaFiles -d $outputPath

And after to convert to jar: 
jar cvfm "H:\_myapp\.jar\myapp.jar" "H:\_myapp\myapp\src\resources\MANIFEST.MF" -C "H:\_myapp\out" .

It says Error: Could not find or load main class

See the tag wiki section on Packaging for other deployment strategies.

Try this.

Is your goal to create an actual "fat" JAR file? Or are you just trying to create a normal executable JAR file? If the former, your commands don't show any attempt at creating a fat JAR. If the latter, what is the java command that resulted in "Error: Could not find or load main class" (or are you saying the error came from your jar command)? What is the content of your MANIFEST.MF file?
